# Regular Expression to extract hour minute second from a line

Tags: java, regex, parsing, date, calendar

I have the following line

```
STATUS | webapp | 2014/05/26 15:03:13 | Starting the service...
```

Now I shall have to extract hour minute and second from the line..

I came up with this code..

```
 BufferedReader bin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wrapperFile));
 s = bin.readLine();
 final Scanner sc = new Scanner(s);
 final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
 while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        final String line = sc.nextLine();
        final Date date = dateFormat.parse(line);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.print(calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
 }
```

But parser exception was thrown.. Is there any workaround to this problem..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Complete solution here:

```
    String input = "STATUS | webapp | 2014/05/26 15:03:13 | Starting the service...";
    String[] splitted = input.split("\\s\\|\\s");
    String dateTime = splitted[2];
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        Date d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss").parse(dateTime);
        c.setTime(d);
        System.out.println("Year: " + c.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println("Month: " + c.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println("Day in month: " + c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println("Hour: " + c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        System.out.println("Minute: " + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println("Second: " + c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
    catch (Throwable t) {
        // test
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Output**

```
Year: 2014
Month: 4 // 0-based!
Day in month: 26
Hour: 15
Minute: 3
Second: 13
```

Answer (score 3):

```
([0-9]{2}:){2}[0-9]{2}
```

will match HH:MM:SS

Comment: Fixed, making it a little more verbose

Answer (score 1):

Split the input `String` using the `|` separator, then use a `SimpleDateFormat` with pattern `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss` on 3<sup>rd</sup> array element returned from `split`